# How to go through an array and get values which I want to use in an sql query and store the retrieve value in an another array?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store three variable values in an array. These are HomeResult, Draw and AwayResult. Which I want to use in an another php file. In the image u can se the final website. Problem is I can get the names of the teams and also the value of rows but result is not success.

Or is there another way to achieve this goal ?

I am not sure if it is the goed way to use B,E,F and O variable form the include php.
code of final site;

```
<table class="table">   
<thead> 
    <tr>
        <th>Home Team</th>
        <th>Away Team</th>
<th>Result</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>E</th>
<th>F</th>
<th>O</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
include 'ff.php';
include 'result.php';

foreach ($champs as $champ ) :
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $champ['HOME'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $champ['AWAY'];?></td>
<td></td>
<td><?php echo $champ['B'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $champ['E'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $champ['F'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $champ['O'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

[image]

file result.php

```
include 'champs.php';

$HomeWins=0;
$Draw=0;
$AwayWins=0;

foreach ($champs as $champ ) :
    $B =$champ['B'];
    $E=$champ['E'];
    $F=$champ['F'];
    $O=$champ['O'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM England where B = '$B' AND E = '$E' AND F = '$F' AND O ='$O' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        // output data of each row 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            if($row['Q'] == 1){
                $HomeWins++;
            }
            elseif($row['Q'] == 0){
                $Draw++;
            }else{
                $AwayWins++;
            }

        }

        $HomeResult =round(($HomeWins/$rowcount )*100);
        $DrawResult = round(($Draw/$rowcount )*100);
        $AwayResult =round( ($AwayWins/$rowcount )*100);

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
endforeach;
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: There must be a more elegant solution to this from a SQL side. I'm not sure exactly where you're saying it is failing. Can you give some more information? Also, why do you have the `$rowcount` variable being set? You're also looping through champs and then through the row fetch. That's pretty inefficient, so it would be best to achieve this in some other way if possible. I would think a count with distinct would be best. Add something like `Q = 1` and `DISTINCT` but do `SELECT COUNT(*)` or something. In other words, elaborate on where the error is and look up some more elegant ways to query.

Comment: You're never printing `$HomeResult`, etc.

Comment: You're overwriting those 3 variables each time through the `foreach` loop. Maybe you should put them in an associative array, so you can print them in the loop in the first script.

Comment: I think it should be a good solution but I am very new in php. I really don't know how to do that. Can you please show me the way to do that ? Thank you.